# Access PivotTable model from C#

Tags: c#, pivot-table

I intend to build a standalone solution where my .Net app is able to access a PivotTable model  (measures/dimensions). My application should be completely independent of any calculation logic and just be able to read the data.

Open to any other suggestions, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? A PivotTable is a feature of *Excel*. "Offline" doesn't make much sense in this question - even if you wanted to use Interop with Excel, you wouldn't need a connection to anything. In any case, any library that can read Excel cell values, can read a PivotTable's *saved* cell values. It can't make the PivotTable update its data, that requires Excel

Comment: what do you mean "consume data from a PivotTable"? PivotTable representation highly depends on the format or library used for calculating pivot table data.

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko no it doesn't. It's a well defined element of the XLSX format. If the sheet was saved with data, you can read the cells if you know their address.  *Calculating or updating* the saved/cached data is what depends on the library.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, you're right that I didn't explain it clearly. Let me try to rephrase the question. If you have a PowerPivot model and you performed some analysis on it using a PivotTable, and now you'd like to access your measures/dimensions in your .Net app, how would you do recommend approaching this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So I presume that .NET Interop Assemblies for Excel do not expose any of the PowerPivot APIs?

Comment: PowerPivot has nothing to do with PivotTable. They are completely different products. It's like a database (PowerPivot) and the grid you use to display data (Pivottable). If you want to load data from SSAS Tabular (the server-side incarnation of PowerPivot), you should be looking for AMO and AMD.NET. You can also work with the PowerPivot object model from inside Excel or through interop. You *can't* work with the XML directly though, because that schema isn't documented. Check [MSDN's section on the PowerPivot object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn133245.aspx)